# GMSAutoComplete not showing correct position on map when finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsautocomplete

I am using Google Maps API Autocomplete in my Objective C view to allow a user to search an address then be displayed on my map on my application. This is working fine and the auto complete view loads, allows you to fill it out and then disappears and displays your address in the address text box. The map does not get positioned at your location, instead seems to stay on the previous location unless you move the map it will then reload and it will show the address you typed into the auto complete. I will post the code below for the auto complete finishing and disappearing.

```
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {


    // Do something with the selected place.
   // [self.locationclickText setTitle:place.name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    latitude2=place.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude2=place.coordinate.longitude;
    NSString *placeName=place.name;
    self.address.text=placeName;
  //  NSString *placeID=place.placeID;


    [_mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude) zoom:17]];


   // NSLog(@"Place ID %@", placeID);
    //NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your question here. Are you asking why your MapView (`_mapview`) doesn't automatically get updated when you select a place (requiring you to call `animateWithCameraUpdate` yourself)?

If so, then the answer is that it's working as intended. Instances of `GMSAutocompleteViewController` don't magically know about `GMSMapView`'s in your app and don't try to control them.